# Deployed angular application on Github pages doesn't show the application components

Tags: angular, github-pages

I tried to deploy my static app project on Github pages, I ran the command (ngh --dir dist/project-name)
and it generated a dist folder with an index.html file in it.

The problem is when I serve my angular project, the page loads all the components perfectly. but when I go to the github link of the project. it display the only content found in dist/index.html.

Do you know how to make it read the components inside the <app-root> component ?
Thanks in advance

[The ng serve result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEJ3M.jpg)
[The empty github website link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpzU3.jpg)

[The dist/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWykh.jpg)

[if I added an  in dist/index.html it will be displayed normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjuui.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Github pages for some time, but the problems seems to be with the base link

I just checked my repo and this is what I have as the base link:

`<base href="/">`

Can you please try this?

Comment: Thanks, I did that but the page is still empty :/

Comment: Can you try /KareemLandingPage/ (with or without the slash in the end, i'm not sure), cause I just noticed the structure of your project.

Comment: I typed <base href="https://kareemyasser8.github.io/KareemLandingPage/">
and one time <base href="https://kareemyasser8.github.io/KareemLandingPage">
as you mentioned and the result is still the same.

Comment: Can you try with a `/` in the end of the links <base href="kareemyasser8.github.io/KareemLandingPage/">

Comment: I tried that too, still doesn't work. (one side question: I type  ngh --dir dist/kareem-landing-page ) in the terminal each time I change base href line. Am I doing right ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kareem, your question here helped me to find solution!
The github pages take you to a link which has your repo in its url.

**https://[yourgithubusername].github.io/[repositoryname]/**

If you name your repo the same as your app this should work by default.
But if you name your app different from repository name (done that)
only blank page is shown though with files present in inspect window.

What I did before **ngh --dir=dist/[yourappname]** is that I changed base href
to github provided link, so...

**ng build --base-href="https://[yourgithubusername].github.io/[repositoryname]/"**

...and it worked.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Vla, It is so nice that my question which I posted a year ago could help you solve a current problem you have. Cheers my friend 

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35522323)